# ASP.NET MVC : Actionlink does not navigate to correct action method of same name but different parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have two action methods with same name. And they both are decorated with the Http verbs `'Get'` and `'Post'`, and also their parameter list is different.

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Transaction()

 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Transaction(int recordId)

 @Html.ActionLink("Back to Main page", "Transaction", new { recordId= Model.studentId })
```

Both are named `Transaction`, one takes a parameter while the other does not take any.

The action link intended to call the `Transactions(int recordId)` method when that button hit, always navigates to `Transaction()` but not to `Transaction(int recordId)`.

I have two questions:

1. Why is my code always reaching the method which doesn't have a parameter, even though the action link has a parameter?
2. I have decorated my action methods with `HttpPost` and `HttpGet`,  how I can include the `HttpGet` or `HttpPost` with the action link or with any other form element?

Comment: An `ActionLink` is **always** a `GET` request and therefore **always** goes to the action method decorated with `HttpGet` annotation - it does **NOT** look at any parameter list or anything like that. If you want to call the `POST` action method, you need to have a HTML form and a submit button on that form - that will be a `POST` request to be handled by the method decorated with the `HttpPost` annotation ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ActionLink` is rendered as an `<a href="....">` HTML element and therefore is always a `GET` request and thus always goes to the action method decorated with `[HttpGet]` annotation - it does NOT look at any parameter list or anything like that.

If you want to call the `POST` action method, you need to have a HTML form and a submit button on that form - that will be a `POST` request to be handled by the method decorated with the `[HttpPost]` annotation ...